# How to change the deployment region of a google cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sdk, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a google cloud function using the google SDK... the problem occurs when I deploy using the following command:

```
gcloud functions deploy my-first-function --entry-point HelloWorld.Function --runtime dotnet3 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated
```

The problem is that after executing the above command, the function region looks like this:

[image]

the region comes as **us-central1**. How can I change this region?

Comment: Try adding `--region asia-east1` (any region you want) to the command ? Just make sure the region is mentioned in [this list](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dharmaraj mentioned, there is a parameter to specify the region you want to deploy your function in. The reason your function is being deployed in the region us-central1 is most likely because your gcloud sdk defaults to that region.

Run your command by adding the parameter below:

```
gcloud functions deploy my-first-function --region=<my_region> --entry-point HelloWorld.Function --runtime dotnet3 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated
```

Change <my_region> to one of the [regions listed here.](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations)

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--region

Answer (score 1):

It's common to deploy the same function, with the same name in different region, and to put a load balancer in front. Like that, the request are served in the region the closest to the requester.

You can deploy the functions in the number the region that you want, you won't pay more, it's serverless, you pay only when you use it. However, some region are more expensive that others, be careful.

As CaioT said, use the `--region` parameter to specify it.

You can also set the default region in your gcloud SDK like that

```
gcloud config set functions/region <REGION>
```